# python-xarray: xarray.Dataset.keep?

Tags: python-xarray

I have a fairly large `xr.Dataset` with about 20 Data variables. I am only interested in keeping two of them. I see [`xr.Dataset.drop`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.drop.html) with drop variables for a Dataset.

I'm looking for syntax to keep variables. I tried `f['hs','t01']` and got

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/nethome/rxb826/local/bin/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py",
>   line 662, in _construct_dataarray
>       variable = self._variables[name] KeyError: ('hs', 't01')

If there isn't simply syntax I could have a look at developing xr.Dataset.keep

I can also clunky manually create the Dataset as 
`ds = xr.Dataset({'hs': f['hs'], 't01': f['t01']})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use your getitem syntax using a iterable of variable names:

```
f_with_two_vars = f[['hs','t01']]
```

(See the [`xarray`](http://xarray.pydata.org/) manual section on [Indexing and selecting data](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html) for a more detailed explanation.)